# How to set the value for radio button while editing using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, edit

I've a radio button in my form and when I enter a reference number, I can fetch the corresponding form details along with **source** value using **jQuery**. I don't know how to set that value to radio button. Thank You!

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" class="source" <?php echo ($row['source']=='VAT')?'checked':'' ?> value="VAT">VAT
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" class="source" <?php echo ($row['source']=='CST')?'checked':'' ?> value="CST">CST
```

jQuery

```
$('#gp_no').on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        var val = $(this).val();
        var dataString = "gp_no=" + val;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post_process.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('.source').val(data.source);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

post_process.php

```
if(ISSET($_POST['gp_no'])) {

    $gp_no = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['gp_no']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.gp_no = $gp_no";

    if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $source = $row['source'];
    }
    $json = array($vehicle_no, 'source' => $source);
    $json = json_encode($json);
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: Do you have only one radio button?

Comment: That can't be ID must be unique

Comment: @Franco I've two radio buttons, I've updated the question.

Comment: You may not have 2 elements with the same id in the first place

Comment: Oke you have made some clean up editing. I have now posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the value of a selected radio button you can do this:

```
$('input[name="source"]:checked').val()
```

When you get the response from your ajax call you check your button:

First change this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" class="source" id="VAT" value="VAT">VAT
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" class="source" id="CST" value="CST">CST

$("#"+data.source).prop("checked", true)
```

This assune that your returned value is `VAT` or `CST`

Comment: But I'm fetching the value of radio button from php and assigning it to html page using jQuery

Comment: I have edited the answer and added the code you can use in your ajax response

Comment: I don't understand this `$("#"+data.source).prop("checked", true)`

Comment: You are fetching a value from your database, after this you pass the value to ajax `echo $json;` Here in you have the `source` which will be `VAT` or `CST`. Your buttons have an each an id (VAT and CST). Whet you return this value in the response you pass this in there: this means $('#VAT').prop("checked", true) or $('#CST').prop("checked", true). And this comes in your success handler. Simpler than this I can not make it :)