# Select appropriate radio buttons from JSON via a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting a `JSON` and I'm populating my form's controls with the relevant data. 
All the controls work fine except the `radio buttons`. In my database I have the values for the radio buttons saved as `BIT`.

So, I'm parsing the JSON and looping for each control and assign it's value. However, it seems like I'm doing something wrong for on the `radio buttons` (maybe the case statement or my html). Any ideas?

- I'm using jQuery 1.9

HTML

```
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="myform" value="1" name="testx">
                    YES
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="myform" value="0" name="testx">
                    NO
                </label>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="myform" value="1" name="highdanger">
                    YES
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="myform" value="0" name="highdanger">
                    NO
                </label>
            </div>
```

My loop

```
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         cache: false,
         url: serviceUrl + "/ModuleTask/GetExamination" + qstring,
        // beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     }).done(function (result) {
         var oResult = JSON.parse(result);

         // reset form values from json object
         $.each(oResult, function (name, val) {
             var $el = $('[name="' + name + '"]'),
                 type = $el.attr('type');

             switch (type) {
                 case 'checkbox':
                     $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
                     break;
                 case 'radio':
                     // $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                     //$el.attr('checked', 'checked');
                    // $el.prop("checked", val);
                     //$el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                    // $el.filter('[value="' + true + '"]').val(1);
                     $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                     break;
                 default:
                     $el.val(val);
             }
         });


     }).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
         alert(result);
     });
```

AJAX response

```
{"ExaminationID":1,"UserID":44,"PortalID":0,"bloodcholisterol":1,"bloodldl":2,"bloodhdl":3,"bloodtriglycerides":4,"bloodglucose":5,"bodyweight":6,"bodyheight":7,"bodycircumference":8,"bodyexaminer":"DD","bodycomments":"a1","pressurestarttime":null,"pressureone":100,"pressuretwo":200,"pressurethree":300,"pressureexaminer":"B","pressurecomments":"B1","FileID":null,"agogiartiriakipiesi":null,"agogilipidia":null,"agogisakxarodidiaviti":null,"examinationcomments":"c1","highdanger":false,"sistaseis":"no sistaseis","axiologisiexaminer":"XH"}
```

Comment: Checking radio or checkboxes reflecting the settings you have in your database is not such a big deal. I believe you are getting your json data from an `ajax` call. I don't understand how the function you have posted here has been fired and why you want to do it in this way. Maybe posting some more relevant code will help

Comment: What is the resulting error? Do they populate anything at all?

Comment: @santi-elus No, they don't get populated. No errors

Comment: @Franco I'm loading the data via ajax. the loop is working if the ajax pulls the json data successfully. I'm filling a form when the page loads based on previously saved data.

Comment: I understand that, what I mean is that you can check the radio en checkboxes accordingly to the stored values directly in your ajax succes event without the need to construct a dedicated function.

Comment: @Franco any examples?

Comment: if you post your ajax call and your `php` file so I have an idea about what your response could be. I would be happy to help you. Alternatively if you know how the response is looking like just let me see it.

Comment: You could alse have a look at this post where I was helping someone else for something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903674/how-to-set-the-value-for-radio-button-while-editing-using-jquery/ Just look how you can set the id attribute for your radio buttons and how to check it according to the returned response.

Comment: @Franco I have posted more info. It's not php, it's asp.net, but using only html.

Comment: @Franco The ajax includes all the controls, not just the radios

Comment: Are ALL those values in the response related to radio and checkboxes

Comment: The value of this radio returns `"highdanger":false, and should return 1 or 0. I dont know which you others radio buttons are and the comments starts to become very large. A better shut for you, at this point is to post a new question. Add in the question the response and the complete `html` page so it is possible to see which are the checkboxes, radios and inputs. If I am still here I will be glad to help you out but for sure with the complete data shown also someone else can be able to help you. As you see this is really important as untill now no one else has posted any answer here :) :)

Comment: I don't agree with Franco. Your question is fine and what you're asking for is not anything complex or hard to understand. Leave your question as-is and someone will answer it.

Comment: Don't worry because this, when the structure of your code is clear posted, can be easily solved.

Comment: @Franco there are textboxes, textareas, and radio buttons, The (type) in the switch loop recognizes it.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET Can you try just doing `$el.attr("checked", true);`?

Comment: @Santi I am not saying the question is complex, and you came here just now. I am saying this comments become to large and it is not what Stackoverflow likes. Posting the additional data will only make everityng more clear. If you have the answer, just now, then feel free to answer. But post the answer and not just stay asking do this or do that.

Comment: @Santi that selects all the 'no' radios

Comment: @alwaysVBNET Okay, just making sure we could get something selected. Let me Fiddle something for you to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `radio` switch case, you need to first convert your `boolean` to an integer. Filter by this integer value and change the checked attribute to true. Try something like this...

```
case 'radio':
     var i = val ? 1 : 0;
     $el.filter("[value='"+ i +"']").attr("checked", true);
     break;
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qakqo86y/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Haha thanks. I'm a VB.Net guy myself but occasionally I get something right